# La pantalla se bloquea cuando mi modal cierra

Tags: php, html, css, html5

El planteamiento es: tengo los distintos pedidos, a los cuales se les necesita aprobar o rechazar. En cualquiera de las 2 opciones se carga un modal para aprobar y rechazar respectivamente. Ahora, cuando confirmo que quiero realizar la acción la pantalla se bloquea por completo hasta que refresque la página (cabe destacar que sí funciona la aprobación o rechazo)

Este es el código del modal

```
<div id="approveProductModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form name="approve_product" id="approve_product">
                    <div class="modal-header">                      
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Aprobar Orden de Compra</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                    
                        <p>¿Seguro que quieres aprobar este registro?</p>
                        <p class="text-warning"><small>Esta acción no se puede deshacer.</small></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="approve_id" id="approve_id">
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Aprobar">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CODIGO DEL BOTON DE APROBAR**

```
    if($total < $presupuesto ){
        // DELETE FROM  database
        $sql = "UPDATE tblCompras SET estado = '1' WHERE  id='".$id."'";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // if product has been added successfully
    if ($query) {
        $messages[] = "La orden de compra ha sido aprobada con éxito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, la aprobación falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
}else{
    $errors[] = "Sobrepasa el presupuesto permitido para su departamento.";
}
    } else 
    {
        $errors[] = "desconocido.";
    }
if (isset($errors)){

            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong>Error!</strong> 
                    <?php
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                                echo $error;
                            }
                        ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            if (isset($messages)){

                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($messages as $message) {
                                    echo $message;
                                }
                            ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
```

ESTE ES EL MODAL
[image: Este es el modal]

La pantalla bloqueada después de confirmar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe cómo podría solucionar esto?

Archivo main.js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    // Dropdown menu
    $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function () {
        $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
            $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
            $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
        } else {
            $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
            $(this).next(".sidebar-submenu").slideDown(200);
            $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        }

    });

    //toggle sidebar
    $("#toggle-sidebar").click(function () {
        $(".page-wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    //Pin sidebar
    $("#pin-sidebar").click(function () {
        if ($(".page-wrapper").hasClass("pinned")) {
            // unpin sidebar when hovered
            $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("pinned");
            $("#sidebar").unbind( "hover");
        } else {
            $(".page-wrapper").addClass("pinned");
            $("#sidebar").hover(
                function () {
                    console.log("mouseenter");
                    $(".page-wrapper").addClass("sidebar-hovered");
                },
                function () {
                    console.log("mouseout");
                    $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("sidebar-hovered");
                }
            )

        }
    });


    //toggle sidebar overlay
    $("#overlay").click(function () {
        $(".page-wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });

    //switch between themes 
    var themes = "default-theme legacy-theme chiller-theme ice-theme cool-theme light-theme";
    $('[data-theme]').click(function () {
        $('[data-theme]').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $('.page-wrapper').removeClass(themes);
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass($(this).attr('data-theme'));
    });

    // switch between background images
    var bgs = "bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4";
    $('[data-bg]').click(function () {
        $('[data-bg]').removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $('.page-wrapper').removeClass(bgs);
        $('.page-wrapper').addClass($(this).attr('data-bg'));
    });

    // toggle background image
    $("#toggle-bg").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.page-wrapper').toggleClass("sidebar-bg");
    });

    // toggle border radius
    $("#toggle-border-radius").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.page-wrapper').toggleClass("boder-radius-on");
    });

    //custom scroll bar is only used on desktop
    if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        $(".sidebar-content").mCustomScrollbar({
            axis: "y",
            autoHideScrollbar: true,
            scrollInertia: 300
        });
        $(".sidebar-content").addClass("desktop");

    }
});
```

Comment: En la consola dispara algún error? Podrás compartir la acción que hace del lado de javascript? Probablemente tengas algún error ahí.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:81)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)

Comment: Parece que te está faltando una librería de javascript, talves una que se llame: *mCustomScrollbar*.

Comment: Al contrario, la función si está y es la que causaba el problema, sin embargo no me arregla el problema inicial del bloqueo de pantalla.

Comment: Y si intentas removiendo la modal como tal, seleccionando el `id` que contiene la modal, y a este le aplicas `.remove()` una vez oprimes cualquiera de los botones que contienen la acciones *Guardar-Cancelar*, claro, suponiendo que estés usando Js o JQuery, de esta forma: `$('#addProductModal').remove();`

Comment: Podés compartir el `main.js`? El "bloqueo de pantalla" es porque tira un error javascript y corta el proceso de cerrar por completo el modal. Por eso es que es necesario tener más información del archivo, como para poder evaluarlo.

Comment: @Kleith listo, editado

Comment: Puede que se esté llamando al archivo del `mCustomScrollbar` después del archivo `main.js`. Otra forma de comprobar es comentando toda la línea donde utilizás eso para verificar que tenga el comportamiento deseado.

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que estas "cerrando" el `alert` mas no el `modal` en el atributo `data-dismiss` en el *código del botón de aprobar*, así:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
```

Debe quedar de esta manera:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
```

Aquí un ejemplo:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Modal</h1>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El punto que debí aclarar antes es que cuando cierro el modal con la opcion "Cancelar" no ocurre el error del bloqueo